# python django user not authenticated with user object

Tags: python, django, authentication

Ok I am facing this problem with authentication

```
user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(email="some@email.com")
new_password = form.cleaned_data['new_password']
user_profile.user.set_password(new_password)
user_profile.user.save()
user = authenticate(username=user_profile.user.username, password=new_password)
print(user)
```

When I print user it gives `None`

Why the user is not being authenticated?

Comment: Have you actually set the user's password to the new value?

Comment: ya i have done user_profile.user.set_password(new_password)

Comment: And did you save it?

Comment: yes I did .. I have updated the question

Comment: what might be the issue here ??

Comment: Have you overridden the authenticate function or using django's default authenticate?

Answer (score 0):

The authenticate function from `django.contrib.auth` returns an instance of `django.contrib.auth.models.User` class if the credentials match or None if they don't.

I guess no user with username and password provided by you exists. That is why you are getting None.

I suggest going to the shell and running:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
password = make_password("your_password")
user = User.objects.filter(username="username",password=password)
```

and see what user holds.